# RestTemplate annotated by @LoadBalanced get wrong service address by service name from eureka sometimes

Tags: spring-cloud, resttemplate, ribbon, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I use springcloud to build the system, including many microservices。 For some interface calls, I use resttemplate annotated by @LoadBalance to implement load balancing, and use eureka as a registry center. However， when I call interfaces between different micro services, resttemplate sometimes will connect to wrong service. For example, I have service A, B, C, when service A call a service B's interface, resttemplate annotated by @LoadBalance will find the actual ip&port from eureka by service name first, and then build the actual url and send the request to target server, but sometimes, it will find the service C's ip&port when I call service B's interface, which cause a fail invoking. This case occurs infrequently but nerver disappear, I have been troubled for a long time,  could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you constructed the rest template. What versions are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I learned why yesterday: it is a bug in spring cloud Dalston.RELEASE([link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/224)), and we happen to use this version. Spring cloud had  fixed this bug in Dalston.SR2, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I learned why yesterday: it is a bug in spring cloud Dalston.RELEASE(https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/224), and we happen to use this version. Spring cloud had fixed this bug in Dalston.SR2, and now it works fine

Comment: FYI, Dalston, Edgware and Finchley are no longer supported. Please upgrade to Greenwich or Hoxton.